# Can every spell and enchanted item be found without buying them?

Tags: the-elder-scrolls-v-skyrim

I don't want to pay for magic spells or enchanted items. I haven't bought anything but a house. I'm happy playing like this and I don't want to change it. I know that sooner or later I'll have to buy the master spells, but I don't want to buy any others.

Is it *possible* to find every single magic spell and enchanted item? Or are there items and spells that can only be acquired by paying for them?

Comment: Are you role playing a lonely scavenger?

Comment: @Paystey: I just don't need the help of any follower. IMHO, they just obstruct or get killed (sometimes accidentally by me). They are good mules, but that's the only thing they're good for.

Comment: I edited this to cut out the parts that are irrelevant to the actual question (we don't need to know about your stance on followers to answer this), and clarified the core question. Do revert part or all as necessary.

Comment: @SevenSidedDie: thank you! English is not my native language. I appreciate your help editing the question.

Comment: You say you don't want to *buy* any others. Who says you have to **pay** merchants to get hold of the spell books, sneak is your friend :)

Comment: I rarely if ever have a follower and get along just fine. I'm not sure why that would be a factor. Also, all you need to make money a non-issue is to find (or buy) an item enchanted with Banish, another with Soul Trap, and good supplies of iron, leather, and soul gems. Then you'll quickly find all the merchants in Skyrim put together can't afford your stock of Iron Daggers of Banishing. My point being: I fail to see the utility of this approach - you're *much* better off (and spending *much* less time) just getting your spells/enchantments the "normal" way.

Comment: @Iszi - but it's simply a matter of opinion, when you get down to it. His may not be the most efficient way to play, but it's how he likes to play, which ultimately is all that matters.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The primary means of acquiring spell books in the game is by purchasing them from vendors, especially the mages at the College of Winterhold.

Additionally, some are only available by taking quests from these mages, which requires a relatively high skill in the magic school from which they derive.  If you have limited access to low- and mid-tier spells, getting enough skill experience to get to the level where these quests unlock is going to take forever.

Sometimes you can find a random spell book when looting a high-enough level object.  Spell books are relatively rare loot, though - I can't remember finding very many random books in my travels.

Beyond random loot, there is also not a guaranteed complete set of spell books available by exploration.  A few have guaranteed spawn locations, but it's far from complete.

Enchanted items are likewise not guaranteed loot.  In fact, a considerable quantity of the guaranteed enchanted items can't be disenchanted.  Quest rewards and unique items tend to have unique enchantments that can't be learned.  Generally only loot you find randomly can be disenchanted.

You could theoretically avoid purchasing any spell books or enchanted items, but you're probably adding hours of grinding for a relatively slim chance of finding the items you need.

Comment: Thank you for your time. I guess I can use the already learnt enchantments in order to get what I want. I'll let you know whether I find all the spell books and echanted items this way or not (after I reach level 81). Yeah, I know I'm adding hours to the game but, what can I say?, I just love it!

Comment: @user26147, glad it was useful :)  If we managed to answer your question, don't forget to accept it (by clicking the gray checkmark under the score) so that others know it helped.

Comment: I clarified the question some. Do you know if there are any items or spells that are *impossible* to acquire from the random loot lists, i.e., unique or static items/spellbooks that are only available by purchasing them?

Comment: If you want a higher-than-normal chance of finding scrolls and spellbooks, get the Dragonborn DLC and do the [Black Book](http://www.uesp.net/wiki/Dragonborn:Black_Book_%28quest%29) quests.